# Using ConfigurationManager cannot read config

Tags: c#, .net, xml, configuration, configurationmanager

I tried to use ConfigurationManager for the first time so thats what I did:

**1.)** created a new Project (TestProject)
**2.)** rightclick on TestProject -> Add -> New Item -> Application Configuration File (Name: Conf.config)
**3.)** I edited the file so its looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="key1" value="output1"/>
    <add key="key2" value="output2"/>
    <add key="key3" value="output3"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Now If I try to read the config my code is telling me that its empty :/

```
    NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

    if (appSettings.Count == 0) //always true
        Console.WriteLine("something is wrong");
```

Even if I try `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"]` I dont get any output. Hm what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try renaming your config file to `App.config`.

Comment: Is this WPF, Forms or ASP.Net app? Why can't you store the values in the web.config or app.config?

Comment: @Shaks Its a c# console application - and I was using it as it showed here in this tutorial: http://blogs.technet.com/b/vanih/archive/2008/01/25/configurationmanager-class-in-c.aspx

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona Thank you, its working with App.config - So its importan to call the .config always App.config? Im asking myself why does VS give me a choice to for a name if the file should named App.config

Comment: Sorry for the delay, wanted to let you know that renaming the file would solve the problem, as already informed by John. VS gives you and option to name the file as it does not know if you would be using ConfigurationManager to fetch the values from the file. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing testing, then try to mock your environment, instead of accessing configuration files, database, etc.

```
public interface IFooConfiguration
{
    public string Key1 { get; }
    public string Key2 { get; }
    public string Key3 { get; }
}
```

Implement this interface like this:

```
public class FooConfiguration
{
   public string Key1
   {
      get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"]; }
   }
}
```

But for your testing, use mocked configuration (I used Moq for example):

```
Mock<IFooConfiguration> mock = new Mock<IFooConfiguration>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.Key1).Returns("output1");
var sut = new Sut(mock.Object);
```

BTW application configuration file should have name `App.config`.

Answer (score 0):

You should re-build the project, since the fresh config should be copied to the build directory.

Answer (score 0):

Use App.config instead of .config in your Console application. Had the same problem here when trying to use EF6 inside a console project - it just wouldn't work. After a bunch of trial and error, moving the settings to app.config did it for me :)